# Nginx rewrite second path to domain subfolder

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

i tried googling it but did not succeed

I'm using debian + nginx

in config:

> root /var/www/html;

means

> domain.com/*
>   will display everything whats inside of /var/www/html/*

i have another folder

> /var/www/download/*

which should be reachable by

> domain.com/download/*

how do i do that?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }



        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: Heyy, if you can, paste the contents config file here so that people can take a look.

Comment: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default ; added

Comment: can you check on this tony?

Comment: Does `/var/www/download/` contain PHP files? If not, the simple solution is `location /download/ { root /var/www; }`

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks so much